# Interstitial Unity Ads Crashing in iOS in Landscape Mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

Our app starts in portrait mode but switches depending on the game that's being played. The games that display in portrait mode show the Interstitial ads fine but the ones that switch to landscape, crash. I've been fighting with this issue for days now.
I'm using Unity 2020.1.10f1 with Advertisement 3.5.0
This is how the mode is changed:

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
```

> 2020-10-21 13:29:53.237169-0400 App[960:203524] I/UnityAds: +[UnityAds show:placementId:] (line:87) :: Unity Ads opening new ad unit for placement video
> 2020-10-21 13:29:53.437265-0400 App[960:203524] I/UnityAds: +[USRVApiSdk WebViewExposed_logInfo:callback:] (line:70) :: Opening performance ad with orientation LANDSCAPE
> 2020-10-21 13:29:53.445555-0400 App[960:203524] Uncaught exception: UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation: Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [UADSViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES
> (
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018b7af5c0 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 1185216
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019f82942c objc_exception_throw + 60
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018b6aba9c 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 121500
> 3   UIKitCore                           0x000000018d9e9794 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 4839316
> 4   UIKitCore                           0x000000018d9d9f44 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 4775748
> 5   UIKitCore                           0x000000018d9e916c 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 4837740
> 6   UIKitCore                           0x000000018d8c42fc 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 3638012
> 7   UIKitCore                           0x000000018d8b98b4 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 3594420
> 8   UIKitCore                           0x000000018d9ddf90 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 4792208
> 9   UIKitCore                           0x000000018d9e150c 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 4805900
> 10  UIKitCore                           0x000000018d9e2430 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 4809776
> 11  UIKitCore                           0x000000018d9e2784 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 4810628
> 12  UIKitCore                           0x000000018d9e237c 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 4809596
> 13  UIKitCore                           0x000000018d9e2860 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 4810848
> 14  UnityFramework                      0x000000010577c468 __153+[UADSApiAdUnit WebViewExposed_open:supportedOrientations:statusBarHidden:shouldAutorotate:isTransparent:withAnimation:homeIndicatorAutoHidden:callback:]_block_invoke + 388
> 15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018b3abfd0 8E662F82-B1E4-3E7E-A376-18E9755A8F51 + 8144
> 16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018b3adac8 8E662F82-B1E4-3E7E-A376-18E9755A8F51 + 15048
> 17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018b3bb04c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 836
> 18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018b72c1e4 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 647652
> 19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018b7263b4 472C9193-115D-34CD-AD1D-0E7E091C9432 + 623540
> 20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018b7254bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
> 21  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001a21aa820 GSEventRunModal + 164
> 22  UIKitCore                           0x000000018e0c9734 47154C6D-47DF-3ABB-A152-56B159B014E4 + 12048180
> 23  UIKitCore                           0x000000018e0cee10 UIApplicationMain + 168
> 24  UnityFramework                      0x0000000104909bc4 -[UnityFramework runUIApplicationMainWithArgc:argv:] + 108
> 25  App                                 0x000000010286be1c main + 68
> 26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000018b3ece60 90A4E82E-250C-35E3-8B2D-51D6D8B1119B + 3680
> )
> 960: CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-1197/ProjectRuntime/CFNetworkInternal.h:442)

Comment: are your app supports landscape and portrait mode? enabled on Settings?

Comment: It supports both depending on which game they're playing in the app the orientation changes.

Comment: what I meant is it enabled on player Settings?

Comment: Edit > Project Settings > Player>Resolution and Presentation
and check Default Orientation

Comment: It's set to portrait in the settings since that the app starts in that mode.

Comment: I found a note that says:For iOS, when locking orientation with either the setOrientationPortrait or setOrientationLandscape methods, the SDK will first look at the list of orientations supported by your app and conform to that. If, for example, you set an interstitial ad to display in landscape mode but your app only supports portrait orientations, the ad will show in portrait mode. There are no such restrictions for Android.
so when you force the game to become a portrait and the interstitial works on landscape it will cause issues on ios devices
maybe you can avoid this

Comment: by set Orientation landscape when interstitial appears and returns it back to portrait when the ad finished

Comment: The landscape is the issue. Portrait works fine.

Comment: of course, it is  "the SDK will first look at the list of orientations supported by your app and conform to that" from the note... sorry I've switched it...
again...by set Orientation portrait when interstitial appears and returns it back to landscape when the ad finished
or start the game with landscape and.....the same steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix this is:
In Xcode -> General -> Device Orientation:
Check : Portrait, Landscape Left, Landscape Right.